# How do I get links in PowerPoint to consistently link with specific tabs in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am having a problem getting some links in PowerPoint to consistently link with specific tabs in Excel.

I am preparing a PowerPoint presentation with links in a flowchart that links to a specific tab in Excel Worksheet. I have successfully done this with one link "Zoom" using the hyperlink formula Tools%20for%20SCTrn.xlsx#Zoom 
(See screenshots) [Zoom Links in PPT to Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sz6OU.png)
[Zoom tab Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CFa3.png)

However, when I tried to use the same formula for TeamViewer link in my PowerPoint-specifically Tools%20for%20SCTrn.xlsx#TeamViewer  that pathway did not work as I didn't get the results I wanted of linking to the TeamViewer tab in my Excel Workbook, but instead was taken to the YouTube tab with an error message that reference isn't valid, which is confusing in of itself.(See screenshots) [TeamViewer Links in PPT to Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7afQ.png)
[TeamViewer tab Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbs0X.png)

I have removed the links and repeated the process several times but still not successful as I keep getting the You Tube tab and error message, even when I try other hyperlinks. I am not a coder, so don't know if visual basic programming is the culprit putting a code in that is interfering with the linking process but I am interested in learning what is going on as I will be doing more presentation like this in the future and would like to find a resolution. Ideally, if anyone is out there that can tell me what I need to do to get a fix soon,I would appreciate it as the presentation is this Monday 3-4th-2019. I can come up with some workaround but it would be great to know what to do as this issue will come up again. Thanks to anyone who can help.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser!  The two images in your post are the same, so it is difficult to see what results that you are trying to compare.  Please [edit] your post instead of adding information in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Process: Assign a name to a cell so you can reference it in the PowerPoint hyperlink

In Excel:

1) Select a cell in the Excel sheet

2) Click Formulas | Defined names | Define name

3) Type a name (like TeamViewer)

4) Click "Ok"

In PowerPoint:

1) Select the shape you want to assign the hyperlink to

2) Click Insert | Links | Link

3) Type the address / browse to the excel file and select it

4) At the end of the address add the # symbol and the name you defined in step 3 of the "In Excel" process

5) Click "Ok"

Give it a try

Comment: Thank Ricardo - your techniques worked - having now done this 6 times getting the same results, I have the consistently I was looking for.  The key that I wasn't doing was defining the cell, instead I simply writing in the tab name in the hyperlink pathway, which wasn't correct. That is what's important.  Thanks again.

Comment: Great, please consider marking this answer